# angular.copy reflects changes in assigned variable

Tags: angularjs

```
 var democart= angular.copy($rootScope.cart);
 var cartCopy = democart;
```

Somewhere in my code, I am updating the value of `$rootScope.cart`.

That leads to change in value of `cartCopy` as well which I believe should not be the case.

How do I avoid changes in `$rootScope.cart` to be reflected in `cartCopy`?

Note: `$rootScope.cart` is an array of objects.

Comment: i think your scope expression evaluating after rootscope variable  is validated

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, I just did a quick test and it did not happen:

```
$rootScope.cart = {};
var democart= angular.copy($rootScope.cart);
var cartCopy = democart;

$rootScope.cart.test = 4;

console.log('$rootScope.cart', $rootScope.cart); // { test: 4 }
console.log('cartCopy', cartCopy); // {}
console.log('democart', democart); // {}
```

Here's a jsFiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/z7g9cz1o/

Comment: I have checked and rechecked.It is changing my value in cartCopy